# DNS Server not propagating sub-domain

Tags: macos, dns

This is complex, so please bear with me. We are a small company with an internal DNS server. We manage our own FTP and mail, but host our website remotely (Bluehost). We are using Mac OSX 10.3 (Panther) Server software to route users behind our firewall. I recently created a new sub-domain for a mobile version of our website (m.mysite.com). It works fine fine remotely or from a proxy server. It does not work at our office behind the firewall. Is there something wrong with my zone records?

Here is my local zone record:

```
Type  From              To
NS    mysite.com        ns.mysite.com
A     ns.mysite.com     10.0.0.100
A     ical.mysite.com   10.0.0.100
A     mail.mysite.com   10.0.0.101
A     ftp.mysite.com    10.0.0.103
A     mysite.com        74.220.195.50 (my remote webhost IP)
A     www.mysite.com    74.220.195.50
MX    mysite.com        mail.mysite.com
A     m.mysite.com      74.220.195.50 (does not work!)
```

Here is an exerprt from the zone record on my remote webhost:

```
Type  From              To
A     @                 74.220.195.50
A     localhost         127.0.0.1
A     mail              17.149.160.49 (my office's IP)
A     ftp               17.149.160.49
A     m                 74.220.195.50
A     www.m             74.220.195.50
```

I tried dumping local caches and rebooting all the local machines. No joy. Everything works EXCEPT m.mysite.com. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? BTW these aren't the real remote IPs. I am using these for illustrating the problem.

Comment: 17.149.160.49 **is a not** a local address IP, you shouldn't be using it in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a DNS server who talk to Internet, you'll need another server. Your DNS server called primary will have to be visible on the Internet. Your second DNS server, will be used locally.

Your primary server will hold routable IP address over Internet.

Your secondery server will hold routable IP address over Ethernet (your LAN).

Primary server example :

```
Type  From              To
NS    mysite.com        ns.mysite.com
A     ns.mysite.com     74.220.195.50
A     ical.mysite.com   74.220.195.50
A     mail.mysite.com   74.220.195.50
A     ftp.mysite.com    74.220.195.50
A     mysite.com        74.220.195.50
A     www.mysite.com    74.220.195.50
MX    mysite.com        mail.mysite.com
A     m.mysite.com      74.220.195.50
```

Secondery server example :

```
Type  From              To
NS    mysite.com        ns.mysite.com
A     ns.mysite.com     10.0.0.100
A     ical.mysite.com   10.0.0.100
A     mail.mysite.com   10.0.0.101
A     ftp.mysite.com    10.0.0.103
A     mysite.com        10.0.0.100
A     www.mysite.com    10.0.0.100
MX    mysite.com        mail.mysite.com
A     m.mysite.com      10.0.0.100
```

So the idea behind that is

```
    Everyone
       |
      You
       |
     Router
    |      |
    A      B
```

A : Visible on the Internet - DNS, Web server, whatever you want (you route your domain there)

B : Local DNS server, you use it as primary and secondy DNS server inside your lan connection.

In the office, your computer will ask B and your gonna get the internal IP address of A. So you gonna see the page of the server A.

On the Internet, your gonna see computer A and your gonna ask server A.

Your computer will look at B for the DNS resolving thing before going to A and since B should hold your assignement, your computer will get your internal IP address of your server.

Comment: But everything is working the way it is set up, except for m.mysite.com. Why would www.mysite.com work, but not m.mysite.com? They are configured identically.

Comment: I can't tell, but I can tell that your setup is wrong. You cannot have a DNS server that do Internet/LAN assignement for the same thing.

Comment: Did you create a subdomain on your remote web host ? Your webhost manage your domain DNS ? Your webhost server httpd (apache, tomcat, whatver) hold a conf file to resolve your subdomain ? Are you able to ping your sub-domain ?

Comment: Yes. Subdomain works fine remotely or if I go through a proxy server. It is invisible only this side of firewall. Can't ping it from this side either. So I should have two DNS server on this side of the firewall?

Comment: David, thanks for your feedback. Besides the setup being wrong, it is an ancient version of mac server.

Comment: You should have a server just behind the router and one behind everything (for your network). I don't know MAC well... Try a cname instead of a host

Comment: Thanks so much for your help David! We currently use a commercial webhost with their own DNS, and we have another DNS server behind our router/firewall. So we need another DNS server on the other side of the firewall, between us and the webhost? This is really confusing me (sorry)!

Comment: What I would do is put a DNS server directly behind the router (so your office IP resolve to your DNS server) and another DNS server behind the firewall so your lan's computer can resolve from this DNS.

This way you can manage the DNS from Internet and the DNS from the LAN. This is how it work at my home. I got 2 DNS server, one in front and one behind. So if I go to let's say mywebsite.com from my office, I will resolve my first DNS (primary behind router) to let's say my home IP is 1.1.1.1 and if I go to mywebsite.com from my lan, I'll resolve to 192.168.1.101.

Comment: By default, you shouldn't never use a DNS for internal and external DNS. Never. You need to resolve the kind of IP you looking for : LAN -> resolve LAN address for everything local and Internet - resolve Internet address for everything on the Internet. Also, never use non-local address IP in your local network. The address you can use in IPv4 are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16. It give you in total near 17,891,328 address IP to assign, enough for a company.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll look into reconfiguring and let you know how it turns out!

Comment: Aaaaargh! I didn't have a trailing "." after the domain. All "from" domain names should end with a . i.e. "m.mysite.com." NOT "m.mysite.com"

Comment: Ahhh, didn't see that. Good one. But remember it shouldn't be done this way.